# regex, remove all but one character in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need your help.

I need to remove a pattern from a text file  `,"refresh":18});`

But I don't need to delete curly bracket in this pattern, I need to save it.

My code

```
...
echo $data2 = str_replace(",\"refresh\":18});", "", $data);
...
```

How to change my regex to remove the pattern, but don not remove } charecter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just replace the whole pattern with character '}' ???
Just try:

```
echo str_replace(",\"refresh\":18});", "}", $data);
```

Comment: @Alex Lian no problem :P